# Binding error property not found on 'object'

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, dependency-properties

I'm stuck with a broken binding, normally this approach works fine but now i cant get it to work. It's really simple, i have a usercontrol with a Ellipse, this ellipse has to change color depending on a DependencyProperty of type boolean. However it doesn't seem to find the DependencyProperty. Search for several hours tried lot's of different this, but can't get it to work. I think it's because it's Friday?

XAML:

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="NTP_Status"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    d:DesignHeight="100"
    d:DesignWidth="100"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Ellipse
        Width="100"
        Height="100"
        StrokeThickness="2">
        <Ellipse.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Ellipse}">
                <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Red" />
                <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="Black" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Orange" />
                        <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="Navy" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsSyncing, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Green" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsSyncing, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Fill" Value="DarkGreen" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Ellipse.Style>
    </Ellipse>
</UserControl>
```

VB.net:

```
Public Class NTP_Status

    Private Shared ReadOnly IsSyncingProperty As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("IsSyncing", GetType(Boolean), GetType(NTP_Status))

    Public Property IsSyncing As Boolean
        Get
            Return CBool(Me.GetValue(IsSyncingProperty))
        End Get

        Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
            Me.SetValue(IsSyncingProperty, value)
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have a Style for Ellipse. Binding with `{RelativeSource Self}` means that Binding will try to find property `IsSyncing` in Ellipse object, which fails because `IsSyncing` is declared in UserControl.

use `RelativeSource AncestorType`

```
Binding="{Binding Path=IsSyncing, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"
```

or give UserControl a name (`x:Name="myControl"`) and use ElementName:

```
Binding="{Binding Path=IsSyncing, ElementName=myControl}"
```

also `Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true"` should be the last one, otherwise DataTriggers for IsSyncing will always overwrite it

Comment: Are you sure this will work ? Binding="{Binding Path=IsSyncing, ElementName=myControl}". I think not, because again you are looking for IsSyncing on myControl :)

Comment: @OlaruMircea, IsSyncing is a DP of NTP_Status UserControl. if that control is named "myControl" then ElementName should work

Comment: @ASh I think you need to add DataContext.IsSyncing instead of just IsSyncing. UserControl should not have that property on it but on its DataContext. Am i wrong?

Comment: @OlaruMircea, UserControls usually have many DP and no special DataContext type. Consumers of UserControl should be able to set constant attributes: `<NTP_Status  IsSyncing="True"  />`. UserControl shouldn't assume that there is some DataContext at all. And if there is DataContext, UserControl shouldn't make assumptions about property names.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using `{RelativeSource Self}`on your Ellipse you should have that **IsSyncing** property on the Ellipse control.

Which surely is not the case and I think you should make use of Path= **DataContext**.IsSyncing if NTP_Status instance is your DataContext.

Better get rid of that relative source and leave the binding path as it is now.

**Edit:**

I see i was down voted and i don't understand why, maybe the one who did it can explain.

Just note that your `Ellipse` will inherit the `DataContext` from its parent (`UserControl` in this case) so you don't need to use any RelativeSource bindings there.

Comment: NTP_Status is a UserControl (`UserControl x:Class="NTP_Status"`). IsSyncing is a DP of that UserControl. Where did you get that there is a `DataContext`? (and please don't suggest to do `this.DataContext = this;` in UserControl)